# Min-Cost Flow Integrality Theorem

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, network-flow

The min-cost flow problem's integrality theorem states that given "integral data", there is always an integral solution to the problem that corresponds to minimum-cost flow. The notion of integral data is slightly confusing to me as most papers, tutorials say that the demands, supplies and capacities should be integral. Now, a capacity constraint is typically represented as

```
l_i  <=  c_i  <= u_i
```

where `l_i` is the lower bound on the capacity of edge `i`, and `u_i` is the upper bound. In order for the integrality theorem to hold, is it enough that `l_i and u_i` are integers? The doubt comes from the fact that this doesn't necessarily mean that the flows are always integers themselves as for example, for `l_i = 0, u_i = 1`, edge `i` can have a flow of 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what the integrality theorem says.

If all of the `l_i` and `u_i` are integers, and **any** feasible solution exists, then there must exist a solution where all flows are integers.

This does not mean that all solutions must be integers.  Just that at least one will be.

Comment: Thank you. Does it say say that a solution with all integral flows exists? Or is it stronger? My understanding was that an integral flow would exist which will be no worse than any fractional flow. Also, can you point me to the proof for this? It is weird that papers and tutorials take it for granted without a) proving it or b) citing the original proof.

Comment: It is stronger.  The max flow will match the min cut, and there is a solution with a max flow and all integral flows.  See http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos423/lectures/07maxflow.pdf for a proof.